# CodeIgniter load helper, language and library for Admin Area Only

Tags: php, codeigniter

This has been asked a few times and I have seen tutorials yet i failed to do it. I basically have abc.com/admin then admin/controllers. What I need is to load some languages, helpers and libraries for admin area.

```
    class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{         

        function __construct(){
          parent::__construct();
          }

      }


    class Admin_Controller extends MY_Controller{
         function __construct(){
          parent::__construct();
          file_put_contents('trial.txt','trial data');                 //JUST TO SEE IF THAT EVEN WORKS and it is not writing the file either
        $this->lang->load('scripts','english');
   }
}
```

Nothing is loaded in all Admin areas, unless I autoload them in autoload.php. What am I missing?

Comment: For helper `$this->load->helper('url_helper.php'); `

Comment: For library  `$this->load->library('class_name');`

Comment: For language `$this->lang->load('error_messages_lang', 'english');  in that make sure your language file will be `application-> language->english->error_messages_lang.php   like this...
`

Comment: @DivyeshPatoriya what if it doesn't load? Thats the problem I am having...they dont load.

Comment: Please enable error reporting and share the error...

Comment: What is error message??

Comment: @DivyeshPatoriya `$this->load->helper('url')` is correct syntax. [Check the docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/helpers.html#loading-a-helper).

Comment: Is `Admin_Controller` class in `MY_Controller.php` file, or is it separate file in `core` directory?

Comment: @DivyeshPatoriya and Mehul: for language files, the error is the line is not found, which makes sense since the language file is not loaded at all. The helper functions raise function not found error

Comment: @Tpojka it is in the same MY_Controller file. Even the public MY_Controller is not having effect as well.

Comment: Can you share the code of controller that is extending `Admin_Controller`?